# Can I stop java.util.logging from contributing to a memory leak?

Tags: java, web-applications, memory-leaks, java.util.logging

After stopping my web app, a significant amount of PermGen is not being released. The culprit seems to be the WebappClassLoader (in Tomcat, but it happens in Jetty too), which is kept in memory by references from a bunch of other objects. The following image shows that objects that refer to WebappClassLoader, and the things that refer to them, and so on.

[image]

One of the clingy objects seems to be an instance of `net.lag.logging.Level$INFO$`, to which a reference is stored in the static `known` array in `java.util.logging.Level`.

It appears that `java.util.logging.Level` keeps a static reference to all instances of itself. Bad, nasty `java.util.logging.Level`! Can I do anything about it? The java.util.logging framework is used by a third-party library, so I don't think I have the option of not using it.

Comment: What unit is that, bytes? Logging is using up 8 bytes and you are worried about it?

Comment: Yes, it's bytes, and no I don't care about 8 bytes. I do care that a reference to WebappClassLoader prevents it from being garbage collected; and it accounts for about 10 megabytes.

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: Also, *Level* (as opposed to Logger) instances are a small, fixed set, e.g. INFO, FINER, etc. Is some web app creating a new subtype? Otherwise, why would the instance keep the webapp from being GC'd?

Comment: If it's any consolation, [this has long been a known issue with the Level class](http://blogs.sun.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java), and Sun engineers were discussing filing bugs against the class... [four years ago](http://blogs.sun.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java#comment-1162179588000).

Comment: @Dilum: I'm using JDK 1.6.0_21.

Comment: @Dilum: Yes, there's a Configgy library that creates it's own net.lag.logging.Level$INFO$ instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of making Sun fix the Level implementation or changing your library to do away with its custom Level, the only way I can think of is moving the library out of the web application classloader and into the container (shared or common classloader).

If you do this, there will still be the custom instances of Level, but they will no longer be linked to the web application. So that if you bounce the webapp, it will keep recycling the same Levels (not leaking new ones).

Of course, this will affect the classloader for the library, and it might break. Some things need to be in the web application and cannot be moved to the container. Even if the library continues to work, it might itself keep similar references to other parts of the web application around, which would be the exact same problem again. Still, give it a try.

Comment: See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6543126 for the relevant bug report.